# OpenGL draw buddha using .obj file. EDIT: Creating Normals issue

Tags: c++, c, opengl, draw, normals

I am reading a file (buddha.obj) that contains the object vertex (v x y z) and faces (f v1 v2 v3) (49.990 vertex and 100.000 faces). Each face is a triangle. Here is an example:

```
v 0.198158 -0.316753 -0.908867
v -0.259644 -0.25891 -0.763365
v 0.103703 0.362585 -0.709771
f 17549 29522 33195
f 17549 21976 39266
f 49008 29523 36155
```

For example, the last face comprises vertex 49008, 29523 and 36155.

I read the file and keep the records in two bi-dimensional arrays:

```
vert[numVer][1]
face[numFace][2]
```

Where numVer and numFace are the total of vertex and faces, respectively. Vertex contains x, y and z coordinates and Faces contains vertex 1, 2 and 3.

Everything is perfect until this point. My problem begins when I try to draw the buddha in my screen.

My code is basically like this:

```
void init (void){
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, winWidth, 0.0, winHeight);
}
```

Display:

```
void display(void){
    // Clear color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    /* Using gluLookAt function */
    gluLookAt(eyeX+centerX, eyeY+centerY, eyeZ+centerZ, 
              centerX, centerY, centerZ, 
              upX, upY, upZ);                           

    /* Rotation tests */
    glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );

    /* Load Internal Parameters (Matrix Projection Mode) */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    // Draw the polygon
    //drawPolygon();
    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    drawObj();

    glFlush();
}
```

The camera parameters are like this (it works fine when I draw a simple polygon that I will show below):

```
GLfloat     eyeX = 3.0, 
            eyeY = 2.0, 
            eyeZ = 5.0,
            centerX = 0.0, 
            centerY = 0.0, 
            centerZ = 0.0,
            upX = 0.0, 
            upY = 1.0, 
            upZ = 0.0,
            fovy    = 100.0,
            aspect  = (float) winWidth / (float) winHeight,
            zNear   = 1.0,
            zFar    = 40.0;
```

My problem is here, when I try to draw the Buddha instead of the cube (Fixed):

```
 void drawObj(void){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < numFace ; i++){
                glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                    glVertex3f(  vert[face[numFace][0]][0], vert[face[numFace][0]][1], vert[face[numFace][0]][2] );
                    glVertex3f(  vert[face[numFace][1]][0], vert[face[numFace][1]][1], vert[face[numFace][1]][2] );
                    glVertex3f(  vert[face[numFace][2]][0], vert[face[numFace][2]][1], vert[face[numFace][2]][2] );
                glEnd();
            }
         }
```

EDIT1: Well, now it works (after changing [numFace] for [i]), but the Buddha is draw as a "white brick", like the image below:

[image: "White brick" Buddha]

[image: "White brick" Buddha]

I tried a solution using glmDraw and it works great, but the perfect solution is to draw by myself.

[image: gglmDraw(objmodel_ptr, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL]

EDIT: Now I am trying to compute normal vector for each face, but the result is not going very well. It appears lots of triangles, not in a good shape. 
I tried (V2-V1, V3-V1), (V2-V1, V3-V2), same results.
Should I also compute normal vectors for each vertex? How would it work?
I am using Flat shade, so I think Face Normals should work. Vertex Normal (Average of faces normals that this vertex belongs) has to be used for Gouraud, right?

```
 void drawObj(void){

    GLfloat v[3] = {0,0,0}, w[3] = {0,0,0}, n[3] = {0,0,0}, lenN;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numFace ; i++){

        w[0] =  vert[face[i][0]][0] - vert[face[i][1]][0],
        w[1] =  vert[face[i][0]][1] - vert[face[i][1]][1],
        w[2] =  vert[face[i][0]][2] - vert[face[i][1]][2],

        v[0] =  vert[face[i][2]][0] - vert[face[i][1]][0],
        v[1] =  vert[face[i][2]][1] - vert[face[i][1]][1],
        v[2] =  vert[face[i][2]][2] - vert[face[i][1]][2],

        n[0] =  (v[1] * w[2]) - (v[2] * w[1]),
        n[1] =  (v[2] * w[0]) - (v[0] * w[2]),
        n[2] =  (v[0] * w[1]) - (v[1] * w[0]),

        lenN = sqrt((n[0]*n[0]) + (n[1]*n[1]) + (n[2]*n[2]));

        n[0] = n[0]/lenN;
        n[1] = n[1]/lenN;
        n[2] = n[2]/lenN;

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glNormal3f( n[0], n[1], n[2] );
            glVertex3f(  vert[face[i][0]][0], vert[face[i][0]][1], vert[face[i][0]][2] );
            glVertex3f(  vert[face[i][1]][0], vert[face[i][1]][1], vert[face[i][1]][2] );
            glVertex3f(  vert[face[i][2]][0], vert[face[i][2]][1], vert[face[i][2]][2] );
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Should be `vert[face[i][0]][0]`. In other words, use `i` as the index, not `numFace`.

Comment: I see just that problem that you use `numFace` as index to array `face`. You don't even get something from array, you get one element from memory after last element of array `face`. Change it to `i` as user above me suggested and try it than.

Comment: Thanks, you were right! That was my bad, I didnt realize that. But I still have a problem. It draws the object, but as a "white brick".

I tried a solution using glmDraw, it works perfect the Buddha. But I should draw by myself, glmDraw does everything in 10 lines.

Comment: I've edited the post with pictures. Thanks user3386109 and Gondil

Comment: I'm not sure but you use `glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` so that's why it is white I think. You have to use appropriate texture for it, and than apply light and shading somehow when you want to see it normally.

Comment: I am not sure either. I am using glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0) for both of them. I added some lightning and upgraded the pictures. 
My glmDraw is like this: glmDraw(objmodel_ptr, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_COLOR)

Comment: I am wondering if it is because I did not created Normal Vectors for faces/vertex. Do you think it can interfere?

Comment: Yes of course it can interfere. 
Truly I never draw 3D with OpenGL so I don't have knowledge about it as I wish to have.
Normal vectors affect, which faces will be shown and covered with texture and which not. Try to use Normals.

Comment: @AlexisHeijmeijer please, get back your changes in your question. When somebody answer you and you change your question to working state, other users do not see what was wrong. Problem should be still in question and solution in answers. I mean get back `numFace` as an index to array. If you added some other problem and you don't want to create new question then mark it clearly, for example **EDIT1: after change this problem occurs**

Comment: @AlexisHeijmeijer Why you use `vert[face[i][0]][0], vert[face[i][0]][3], vert[face[i][0]][4]` ? that does not make sense for me. `vert` should be `vert[numVert][2]` - x,y,z coordinates and `face` should be `face[numFace][2]` as 3 vertices defining triangulate face. 
I think your code should look like this (see indices to arrays):
`glVertex3f(  vert[face[i][0]][0], vert[face[i][0]][1], vert[face[i][0]][2] );
 glVertex3f(  vert[face[i][1]][0], vert[face[i][1]][1], vert[face[i][1]][2] );
 glVertex3f(  vert[face[i][2]][0], vert[face[i][2]][1], vert[face[i][2]][2] );`

Comment: I get back the original posts. Well, apparently the website recognizes ver[face[i][0]][3] as an image, os it is changing automaticaly to 1, 2, 3....13, 14...I am trying to fix it. Sorry about that, it is my first post here. 
I will try to create normals and see the results
EDIT: I added quotes to the code and now itis showing correctly

Comment: @Gondil I now added some normals and the results. Not sure what is going on wrong.